# How can we validate a form using formik when field is filled with state value and want to edit that field?

Tags: reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

This is the code but what I want to know how can I validate the form that is coming filled with the state value and I know how can we validate initial values but unable to understand this.

This is the State here CurrentUserDetails is object from list API:

```
 const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(currentUserDetails.first_name);
```

This is the validation schema:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    first_name: Yup.string()
      // .matches(/^[A-Za-z ]*$/, "Please enter valid name.")
      // .max(40, "First Name must be at most 40 characters.")
      .required("First Name is required."),
  });
```

This is the data I want to send to the API in put API to update the existing data. Data is updating correctly but unable to validate the data.

```
const data = {
      first_name: firstName,
      
    };
```

The field I use to update the `First Name` field:

```
<Field
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setFirstName(e.target.value);
                }}
                as={TextField}
                value={firstName || ""}
                label="First Name"
                name="first_name"
                placeholder="Enter First Name"
                fullWidth`enter code here`
                size="small"
                error={props.errors.first_name && props.touched.first_name}
                helperText={<ErrorMessage name="first_name" />}
                required
                
              />
```

Please help to solve I got stuck there in my project

Comment: check [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formik-yup-forked-gpny7o) you need to add formik `handlChange` or you can also use `setFieldValue`

Comment: it is not resolving throuh this actually it did not need any onChange there.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? I'm using custom validations as of now. But they'll not be triggered onSubmit, They'll just show up onBlur. But I want to show the validation onSubmit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to validate field values only if it change. right? You don't want to show error messages for already filed values in the field?

In your Formik initialisation object, set initial values with the value you getting from the API endpoint. Try as below.

```
const formik: any = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            first_name: firstName
        },
        validate: values => {
            const errrors = {};
            if (!values.firstname) {
               errors.firstNameErr = "Please Enter First name"
            }
        }
)}
```

Inside your your form field. Change like below.

```
<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
   <Field
       onChange={formik.handleChange}
       value={firstName || ""}
       id="firstname"
       ...
   />
   {formik.errors.firstNameErr}
</form>
```